# Ocaml libraries for mp3 editing?

Tags: mp3, ocaml

In **OCaml**, is there any library to manipulate  mp3 files editing (for ex.  splitting, blank detection)? Yes, I see things should have been much easier in other languages.

Comment: Maybe you should precise what kind of edition you want. (tags, filtering, splitting...)

Comment: You can have a look at what they use in [liquidsoap](http://savonet.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stéphane Gimenez mentioned, [OCaml-lame](http://sourceforge.net/projects/savonet/files/ocaml-lame/) from the liquidsoap project is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you find a solution in C (should be easy enough) then you can  [interface it from Ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual032.html).

Comment: I've found this to be quite helpful in dealing with complex types: http://www.linux-nantes.org/~fmonnier/ocaml/ocaml-wrapping-c.php